# Edit Activity Label

Tags: android, xml, label

Right now, the label for my Activity has the name of the current Activity. I am fine with that, but I'd also like to add a feature to the top right corner of my Activity, that I can change. Basically I want it to be a text view that will say "Bluetooth: Enabled" or "Disabled" or "Discovering"

Is there a way to add a secondary label to an Activity? I feel like in one of my first projects I had it set up like that, but now I can't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should make `Custom title bar for that and put textview in layout of title bar.`

- [See this Example](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-create-custom-titlebar)